# Creating a Perl 6 module containing Perl 5 utility scripts in bin/

Tags: raku

### Perl 6 script in a Perl 5 module distribution

I can include a Perl 6 script in a Perl 5 module distribution:

```
# Create a new module
dzil new My::Dist
cd My-Dist/

# Add necessary boilerplate
echo '# ABSTRACT: boilerplate' >> lib/My/Dist.pm

# Create Perl 6 script in bin directory
mkdir bin
echo '#!/usr/bin/env perl6' > bin/hello.p6
echo 'put "Hello world!";' >> bin/hello.p6

# Install module
dzil install

# Test script
hello.p6
    # Hello world!

# See that it is actually installed
which hello.p6
    # ~/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/bin/hello.p6
```

### Perl 5 script in a Perl 6 module distribution

However, I'm having a hard time including Perl 5 scripts in a Perl 6 distribution.

In the module directory is a `META6.json` file and a subdirectory called `bin`. In `bin` is a Perl 5 file called `hello.pl`.

`zef install .` runs without error in the top directory. But when trying to run `hello.pl`, I get an error. Come to find out, a Perl 6 wrapper script had been installed for `hello.pl` and that is what is giving me the error. If I run the original `hello.pl` directly, it works fine.

### `META6.json`

```
{
"perl"         : "6.c",
"name"         : "TESTING1234",
"license"      : "Artistic-2.0",
"version"      : "0.0.2",
"auth"         : "github:author",
"authors"      : ["First Last"],
"description"  : "TESTING module creation",
"provides"     : {
                 },
"depends"      : [ ],
"test-depends" : [ "Test", "Test::META"  ]
}
```

### `bin/hello.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

say 'Hello world!';
```

This installs without error, but when I try to run `hello.pl`, I get the following error:

> ```
> ===SORRY!===
> Could not find Perl5 at line 2 in:
>     /home/username/.perl6
>     /path/to/perl6/rakudo-star-2017.07/install/share/perl6/site
>     /path/to/perl6/rakudo-star-2017.07/install/share/perl6/vendor
>     /path/to/perl6/rakudo-star-2017.07/install/share/perl6
>     CompUnit::Repository::AbsolutePath<64730416>
>     CompUnit::Repository::NQP<43359856>
>     CompUnit::Repository::Perl5<43359896>
> ```

`which hello.pl` from the command line indicated that it was installed in `/path/to/perl6/rakudo-star-2017.07/install/share/perl6/site/bin/hello.pl`. That file is actually the following code:

### `/path/to/perl6/rakudo-star-2017.07/install/share/perl6/site/bin/hello.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
sub MAIN(:$name is copy, :$auth, :$ver, *@, *%) {
    CompUnit::RepositoryRegistry.run-script("hello.pl", :dist-name<TESTING1234>, :$name, :$auth, :$ver);
}
```

I filed a Rakudo bug report (https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=131911), but I'm not totally convinced that there isn't a simple work around.

Comment: Temporary Linux workaround: Make sure the path of the actual `bin` directory comes before `perl6` in `$PATH`.

Comment: The actual bin/ directory contains wrappers. The actual scripts are stored as a hashed filename in a directory with code that may not be a bin script. So I'm not sure that workaround is valid other than allowing you to invoke your script as `D325FA4D04470A8146BDF9869572E1024BDA2BF1`.

Comment: @ugexe You're right. I'm looking at taking a different approach using the `resources` directory and calling scripts using `%?RESOURCES`.

Comment: @ugexe By the way, thanks for all of the hard work on `zef`! I don't know what I'd do without it.

Comment: https://github.com/ugexe/zef/blob/8d62038e239a0d0566065e768c6ad5317ad38624/lib/Zef/Service/Shell/p5tar.pm6#L20 (%?RESOURCES method)

Answer (score 3):

As an example, I created a simple `cat` replacement in Perl 5 and created a Perl 6 module that "wrapped" around it (see the [GitHub repository for it](https://github.com/molecules/p6-wrapper-for-p5-cat) if you'd like to download the code and try it yourself).

Below are copies of the relevant files. After creating these files, running `zef install .` installs fine with my Rakudo Star 2017.07 installation. This installs a `run_cat` executable in your Rakudo `bin` directory.

It seemed like the secret was to make a Perl 6 module file to wrap the Perl 5 script and a corresponding Perl 6 script to use the Perl 6 module.

---

### Perl 5 script

### `resources/scripts/cat.pl`

```
#!/bin/env perl
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<>) {
    print;
}
```

---

### Wrapper scripts

### module: `lib/catenate.pm6`

```
unit module catenate;

sub cat ($filename) is export {
    run('perl',%?RESOURCES<scripts/cat.pl>,$filename);
}
```

### executable: `bin/run_cat`

```
#!/bin/env perl6
use catenate;

sub MAIN ($filename) {
    cat($filename);
}
```

---

### Boilerplate and tests

### META6.json`

```
{
"perl"         : "6.c",
"name"         : "cat",
"license"      : "Artistic-2.0",
"version"      : "0.0.9",
"auth"         : "github:author",
"authors"      : ["First Last"],
"description"  : "file catenation utility",
"provides"     : { "catenate" : "lib/catenate.pm6" },
"test-depends" : [ "Test", "Test::META"  ],
"resources"    : [ "scripts/cat.pl" ]
}
```

### `t/cat.t`

```
#!/bin/env perl6
use Test;

constant GREETING = 'Hello world!';
my $filename = 'test.txt';
spurt($filename, GREETING);

my $p5 = qqx{ resources/scripts/cat.pl $filename };
my $p6 = qqx{ bin/run_cat              $filename };

is $p6, $p5, 'wrapped script gives same result as original';

is $p6, GREETING, "output is '{GREETING}' as expected";

unlink $filename;

done-testing;
```

---

Thanks @moritz and @ugexe for getting me pointed in the right direction!